# using an attribute from a class in python without creating an object

Tags: python, class, import, attributes

I was wondering if it is possible to use an attribute of a class from another file without creating an object from that class, for example, if I have Class_A in File_A and I import Class_A into File_B do I have to use Class_A as an object in File_B in order to access its attributes?

Comment: The whole point of classes is to serve as a template for the creation of objects. Sounds like a fundamental design problem if you want an instance attribute without an instance. Why is this an attribute to begin with, an not a module level variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you provide some sample?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way:

```
In [12]: class MyClass(object):
...:         attr = 'attr value'

In [15]: MyClass.attr
Out[15]: 'attr value'
```

You can use __dict__ attribute also:

> __dict__ is the dictionary containing the class's namespace.

```
In [15]: MyClass.__dict__.get('attr', None)
Out[15]: 'attr value'
```

Use staticmethod decorator if you need to use a method:

```
In [12]: class MyClass(object):
...:         @staticmethod
...:         def the_static_method(x):
...:             print(x)


In [15]: MyClass.the_static_method(2)
Out[15]: 2
```

Comment: Why use `__dict__` when you can access the attribute directly: `MyClass.attr`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, we don't need dict. It just little more handy to deal with missing attributes.

Comment: the problem is whenever I use class.name it says the class has no attribute name even though it does, I've checked the spelling.

Comment: What do you see in: print(class.\__dict__ ) ?

Comment: '{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'armor1' objects>, '__module__': 'the_shop', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'armor1' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x028C1130>}'

Comment: armor1 is the Class and the_shop is the file where I am importing it from

Answer (score 0):

There really is no reason to create a new object in other to utilize the properties and methods of another object.

You only want to create an instance of Class_A in File_B to use it's properties and methods.

For example:

```
import Class_A

#instance of Class_A
classA = Class_A('params')

#property1 is a property in classA
classA.property1

#doSomething is a method in classA
classA.doSomething()
```

Read more about OOP here
http://www.python-course.eu/object_oriented_programming.php

Comment: `classA = Class_A` does not create an instance. I think you want to actually *call* the class object.

Comment: ClassA = Class_A does not work for my code specifically. I have two many classes and the get moved around between two many files